# After applying 'group by' using two fields, duplicate rows are coming. How to groupped the similar rows?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    jiraissue.Assignee,
    CASE WHEN MONTH(jiraissue.RESOLUTIONDATE) = 4 THEN COUNT(jiraissue.ID) END AS '/04/2018',
    CASE WHEN MONTH(jiraissue.RESOLUTIONDATE) = 5 THEN COUNT(jiraissue.ID) END AS '/05/2018',
    CASE WHEN MONTH(jiraissue.RESOLUTIONDATE) = 6 THEN COUNT(jiraissue.ID) END AS '/06/2018',
    CASE WHEN MONTH(jiraissue.RESOLUTIONDATE) = 7 THEN COUNT(jiraissue.ID) END AS '/07/2018'
FROM jiraissue
JOIN resolution resolution
    ON jiraissue.Resolution = resolution.ID
JOIN issuetype issuetype
    ON jiraissue.issuetype = issuetype.ID
JOIN issuestatus issuestatus
    ON jiraissue.issuestatus = issuestatus.ID
WHERE
    issuestatus.pname IN ('Closed') AND
    resolution.pname IN ('Fixed', 'Done') AND
    issuetype.pname IN ('Minor Enhancement', 'Root Cause Analysis', 'Support Demand Request')
GROUP BY
    Assignee,
    MONTH(jiraissue.RESOLUTIONDATE);
```

This is my code.

[this is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LHyA.png)

Now I want the similar Assignee grouped together.

Comment: If I understand your question properly, you just need to remove `,month(jiraissue.RESOLUTIONDATE)` from your `group by` clause

Comment: Hi Nick Thanks for Your quick reply but I want the results group by month as well so I can not remove that

Comment: Your query already groups them by month, that's what all your `case` expressions are for.

Comment: @Nick The OP is trying to do two things at once.  Grouping by the month implies that it wants each month total as a separate _row_.  But the (attempted) conditional counts in the select clause implies that it wants the month summaries as separate _columns_.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess that's why I'm confused, since your answer appears to be essentially OPs query with my suggested change (other than the corrected conditional count clauses) (say that 3 times quickly!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do a pivot query.  Here is a version which should work:

```
SELECT
    jiraissue.Assignee,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(j.RESOLUTIONDATE) = 4 THEN 1 END) AS '/04/2018',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(j.RESOLUTIONDATE) = 5 THEN 1 END) AS '/05/2018',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(j.RESOLUTIONDATE) = 6 THEN 1 END) AS '/06/2018',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN MONTH(j.RESOLUTIONDATE) = 7 THEN 1 END) AS '/07/2018'
FROM jiraissue j
INNER JOIN resolution r
    ON j.Resolution = r.ID
INNER JOIN issuetype it
    ON j.issuetype = it.ID
INNER JOIN issuestatus is
    ON j.issuestatus = is.ID
WHERE
    is.pname = 'Closed' AND
    r.pname IN ('Fixed','Done') AND
    it.pname IN ('Minor Enhancement', 'Root Cause Analysis', 'Support Demand Request')
GROUP BY
    j.Assignee;
```

The basic idea behind the query is that we take conditional counts depending on the month of the resolution date.

Note that if you would be OK with having each month reported as a separate *row* (rather than column), then you could have simply done a `GROUP BY` on the assignee and month.  This query would also be a bit simpler to write.

Comment: Thanks Tim....although I do not have the reputation to give u a up vote but you deserve it